# Почему появляется ошибка при вычитании множеств?

Tags: python, python-3.x

При вычитании  множеств появляется ошибка.

```
fin_news = dict(set(news) - set(old_news))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 55; 2 is required
```

Как её можно решить?

Вот код:

```
def sort_news(pre_news, news):
    old_news = dict(set(pre_news) - set(news))
    news = dict(news)
    fin_news = dict(set(news) - set(old_news))
    return fin_news
```

pre_news и news при поступлении в функцию являются списками.

Comment: А что вы хотите на выходе получить? Конструктор словаря просто не знает, что ему делать с вашими множествами, как их в словарь преобразовать

Comment: Ошибка означает, что элементы множества не являются парами (ключ, значение), поэтому вызов dict не может создать словарь. Из чего у вас состоят news и pre_news?

Comment: на выходе хочу получить список из которого вычтен 2 список. news и pre_news состоят из ключа, который является заголовком новостной статьи и значения, которое является текстом новостной статьи.

Comment: Если хотите получить список, то почему создаете словарь?

Comment: Т.е у меня есть список всех новостей которые я спарсил и список новостей которые я только что спарсил(он очищается в конце программы, чтобы эта функция работала корректно). я хочу сделать чтобы новости не повторялись вот таким методом.

Comment: ошибся, не список а словарь

Comment: Нельзя просто так  сделать из множества словарь, а из словаря - множество.

Comment: а как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Покажите пример того, как у вас выглядят входные данные.

Comment: {'Число заявок на пособие по безработице в США подскочило еще более чем на 3 млн': 'Число продолжающих получать пособие по безработице американцев за неделю, завершившуюся 21 марта, подскочило на 1,226 млн - до 3,029 млн с 1,803 млн на предыдущей неделе.', 'Министр финансов ФРГ предсказал 
спад экономики Германии': 'Немецкая экономика достигнет дна в мае на фоне распространения коронавируса в мире, заявил министр экономики ФРГ.'}

Comment: и почти  такой же 2 словарь

Comment: Но это же не списки (facepalm)

Comment: я знаю, я ошибся, это словари

Comment: @Xander так всё таки, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Xander ошибки нет, но новости которые уже спарсились все равно есть в конечном списке, как это исправить?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: @Xander всё ещё не работает

Comment: я понял в чём была проблема, спасибо за помощь, всё работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sort_news(pre_news, news):
    pre_news = pre_news.items()
    news = set(news.items())
    old_news = set(pre_news) - set(news)
    fin_news = dict(news - old_news)
    return fin_news
```

UPD: Попробуйте так:

```
def sort_news(pre_news, news):
    pre_news = set(pre_news.items())
    news = set(news.items())
    return dict(news - pre_news)
```